# Filter Newsletter feed by interesting tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, newsletter

I am a regular SO user and just received my first SO Newsletter. Its a nice way to keep yourself up-to-date with some interesting questions / answers and get a chance to help with unanswered questions which otherwise would go unnoticed.

The problem is, the newsletter is a random list of questions on the languages and topics which I don't know / understand. It would be nice and interesting for me to get a newsletter of questions of my favourite tags.

For example, my favourite tags include: ruby, ruby_on_rails and javascript. A list of questions, segregated as it is now, with these tags would be great.

I might be the only one in need of this. Does this even make sense?

Comment: More importantly, ignore the tags that I ignore.   I get the boardgames newsletter and have one ignored tag on the site: magic-the-gathering.   The newsletter has 7 new questions this week and 6 are about magic-the-gathering.

Comment: Similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110902/160382

Comment: I wonder why more people don't care about this? I would be clicking every link on the newsletter if it pertained to my interests.

Comment: I also don't understand why more people don't care about this! I love StackOverflow, but 80% of the questions there are about languages and technologies I know nothing about, thus rendering the newsletters mostly useless to me (beyond reminding me to go check out the site).

Comment: Me too on this one. Was searching to see if I had missed something.

Comment: FYI I created a question explicitly about ignore tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169705/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-ignored-tags-on-that-site