# Can newsletters take into account a user's favorite tags on that site?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, newsletter

Stack Overflow is huge and varied. Wouldn't it be great if I could just subscribe to a newsletter with a list of my favorite tags? If I love dealing with [android](/questions/tagged/android), I think it would make sense for my version of the newsletter to focus more on Android questions.

Or, if I sign up for the [Apple SE site](http://apple.stackexchange.com) newsletter, but don't own a Mac, it would be nice if I *my* newsletter would focus on the part of the site I do follow (i.e., iOS).

So I would like to suggest that the newsletters for each site (optionally) take into account the user's favorited and ignored tags for that site.

I know that you can receive emails about specific filters, but I don't think that's a good solution for users who already receive the newsletter. Most of the questions it highlights cover topics that I have no interest in. It would be much better if I could filter out all the noise and get down to *my* likely favorites.

Comment: This is a similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102606/160382

Comment: I would love the newsletter to take into account my favorite and ignored tags. Currently I don't often find much to click on in the newsletters. FWIW Quora seems to do a fairly good job at tailoring their newsletters and I'm much more inclined to click on links in their newsletters.

Comment: FYI - I created a question explicitly about ignore tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169705/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-ignored-tags-on-that-site

Answer (score 2):

+1 I agree with this conceptually, but this will probably require a lot of fine-tuning, and it'll end up being a black magic solution which selects *roughly* X% [android](/questions/tagged/android) content since you have X% recent activity in [android](/questions/tagged/android).

In other words, the newsletter should be able to provide you not just blanket favourite tag activity, but favourite actually-recently-used-by-you tag activity.. since there may be dozens of favourited tags and you may not like a giant wall of text where you have to scroll down to the [android](/questions/tagged/android) section every time to see what you actually want.

Comment: Why can't we just use the actual favorite tags that you've set up on the site? Or, failing that, ignore all of the ignored tags? Why does it have to be a complex algorithm? Or, why can't we use the same algorithm for highlighting "favorite" questions based on *inferred* tags in orange, described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72593/153008)? I don't think this problem is technically difficult.

Comment: Because there's an extra metric at work here. It's part of the duplicate question you worked into this one: the users want *interesting* questions, not just all favourite tag questions. So you need to combine the metric of interestingness with how much the user actually cares about that tag.

Comment: For example, I have [tag:objective-c] favourited as well as [tag:ios] etc, but I'm an `iOS`-only developer. If I was to subscribe to a newsletter with my favourite tags, I'd get a lot of OSX questions which I have no interest or expertise in, but I use [tag:objective-c] in case an `iOS` question is only tagged as [tag:objective-c] (an orange highlight is much less invasive than an email). I'm fine with getting one or two in the email, but not fine with placing both tags on equal ground in terms of favourites. So I think there's going to need to be shades of gray here, hence the `X%` I mention.

Comment: I agree, I think there's a good idea hiding in there somewhere, but it will require some fine tuning.

Comment: darvids0n's point about not wanting all favorite tags to be covered equally makes sense, but I'd much rather have that than have *every* tag covered equally. As it is the newsletter rarely has something in it that pertains to me in any way.

Comment: It mainly depends on how the newsletter works today : is there any algorithm that selects the questions, or is it 100% manual.
Indeed, if there is an algorithm, it should not be too hard to make it generate different newletters according to tags.
If it is manual, maybe several newletter could be created, for us not to read only about C and Java questions.

Comment: @darvids0n I think it is more users want question related to their favorite tags rather than interesting question.. and even then - get the interesting questions only on favorite tags minus the ignored tags. I think SO will be able to use the newsletter better if more people use them, and I think that as it is today, no one wants to see question on subjects they don't care about

Comment: I'm sure many people would be happy if we do nothing this complex. I know I would.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it mainly depends on how the newsletter works today : is there any algorithm that selects the questions, or is it 100% manual.

Indeed, if there is an algorithm, it should not be too hard to make it generate different newletters according to tags.

If it is manual, maybe several newletter could be created, for us not to read only about C and Java questions, as it is the case now.

Eg.

1. Software programming Newsletter (C, C++, Java etc.)
2. Web Client Newsletter (HTML, CSS, and other web technologies)
3. Web Server Newsletter (PHP, Django, RoR, Node.js etc.)
4. Mobile Newsletter (iOS, Android)
5. Algorithmic and Computationnal Newsletter

And everyone picks whichever he is interested into.

In fact, I am always amazed with the data mining potential there is in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Stack Exchange community!

After analysis of community opinions about the current Stack Exchange newsletter, we started to develop its personalized alternative called **StackLetter**.

StackLetter is a result of our university research project. It aims to provide you with an interesting newsletter which solves the drawbacks identified also in this meta question! If you want to read more about our project or register for your personalized newsletter, please, visit https://www.stackletter.com/.

Project is registered as a Stack Exchange application: [StackLetter - A personalized newsletter for the Stack Exchange Network](https://stackapps.com/questions/7657/stackletter-a-personalized-newsletter-for-the-stack-exchange-network).