# Can newsletters take into account a user's ignored tags on that site?

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags, newsletter

I have seen several questions that discuss using your "Favorite" tags to construct a newsletter.   I'm looking for a similar request - but for ignored tags.  I figure it might make sense to split this request from the "favorite" requests because it has different implementation.

Can we exclude questions on the "ignore" tags lists in the newsletter?   For example, I subscribe to the Board and Card Games newsletter.   Currently (and frequently) 6 of the 7 questions are about magic-the-gathering, a tag I have in my ignored list.

I now get a newsletter where at best 1/7 questions is interesting and worth clicking on.

Related questions about using "Favorites":

- [Can newsletters take into account a user's favorite tags on that site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-favorite-tags-on-that-site)
- [Filter Newsletter feed by interesting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102606/filter-newsletter-feed-by-interesting-tags)